# MYSQL “Got an error reading communication packets”

Tags: mysql

The setup is a Windows 2003 Server with MySQL 5.0.45 (it is an old-ish box!)

We've recently started getting warnings in the Application Event Log that say: Aborted connection xxxxx ti db: 'dbname' user: 'dbuser' host: localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

How do I go about identifying the cause of this? This is a live system - are the users getting an error message and if so what would it be?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is [usually](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/communication-errors.html) caused by a client not cleaning up after itself. It could be as simple as a new script that accesses the database and doesn't close the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - we've been through the code and ensured that the connection is closed (at the appropriate point) in all cases.

Answer (score 6):

Would you believe I addressed this kind of question back on Jun 12, 2012 ?

See [**my post in the DBA StackExchange**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19139/877) on why.

### WHAT YOU CAN DO NOW

Try raising the [**max_allowed_packet**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) to a much larger number, since the default is 1M. I would suggest about 10 times the largest TEXT or BLOB field you have in your current dataset.

To set the max_allowed_packet to 256M, you can add it to /etc/my.cnf or my.ini

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=256M
```

to cover future restarts of mysqld. To install the value now on the server, please run this:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd already seen your post and have already increased the max_allowed_packets to 16M, but am still getting this issue. I struggle to believe that the data I'm sending is > 16M...

Comment: You need a much bigger packet. Try 256M. All 256M is not instantiated at the same time. A packer can grow to that size if needed.